# Method to use jQuery show divs with arrow positioned on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking to find out if there is a library or better way in general to achieve having div elements show under a menu or any other items on hover, but with the little arrow pointing out of the created div towards the element that invoked the hover.

My current solution works fine but I feel is a bit of a hack. Does anyone have any idea of a better way to achieve this or perhaps a library that does this well?

By default I've created all of the Div's and have hidden them. The reason for multiple Divs is that I cannot reference the seudo elements to move the position of the arrow for styling purposes. So having hidden all of the Div's i then use a switch passing in the ID of the element that invoked the hover and show the relevant DIV bases on the comparison.

http://jsfiddle.net/LeeroyM/sfvL7c8n/

```
function pop(id) {
    switch (id) {
        case "b1":
            $('#popup1').slideToggle(100);
            break;
        case "b2":
            $('#popup2').slideToggle(100);
            break;
        case "b3":
            $('#popup3').slideToggle(100);
            break;
        case "b4":
            $('#popup4').slideToggle(100);
            break;
        case "b5":
            $('#popup5').slideToggle(100);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I would simplify this is to put on each of the menu circles the target ID of its related popup `<div>`:

```
<div id="b1" data-popup-target="#popup1" class="division circle"></div>
```

With that data attribute, you no longer need to translate the id via your switch statement; you have the element, and you can retrieve the popup id very easily. Instead of:

```
var x = $(this).attr('id');
...
pops(x);
```

You would have:

```
var x = $(this).data('popup-target');
...
$(x).slideToggle(100);
```

No more `pops` function! (Additionally, I would change the variable `x` to have a better name.)

Lastly, each of your `#popup<x>` elements has class `arrow_box`. You could simplify your `hidePops()` function to:

```
function hidePops() {
    $('.popup-wrap .arrow_box').hide();
}
```

- [**jsFiddle Update**](http://jsfiddle.net/sfvL7c8n/3/)

As for a library that does *exactly* what you want, you're probably not going to find one. There are probably several that would be a great starting point, but questions about finding or recommending a tool or library are not suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do realize the general approach could be cleaned up and this has helped. I'm wondering is writing this functionality from scratch usually the best approach or is there a library out there that contributes to this.